# Как получить значение Switch из другого класса (Java Android)

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть switch на MainActivity  (id: switch1) . А также есть MainActivity2
в котором я хочу получить данные о положении switch на MainActivity.

Как это сделать через IF ?

Comment: [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings)

Comment: Используйте сохранение в SharedPreference

Comment: Передавайте значение switch1 во вторую активити при запуске и никакой IF не нужен будет :)

Comment: Пример в студию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared Preferences - хороший вариант для сохранения настроек пользователя.
Пример кода, с помощью которого значение isChecked будет доступно в любом Activity:

**MainActivity**, в котором switch:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
        SharedPreferences mSettings;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            Switch switch1 = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    // при изменении состояния switch новое значение 
                  //будет сразу записано в соответствующее "поле" в Ваших SharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked);
                    editor.apply();

                    if(isChecked){
                        //TODO когда isChecked == true уже по логике программы
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity2**, в котором нужно получить значение:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
    SharedPreferences mSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean isSwitchCheckedInActivity1 = mSettings.getBoolean("isChecked",false);

    }
}
```